# AWS Site to Site VPN to Kerio Control Phase 2 parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 380820527 [ HASH N(INVALID) ]

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, site-to-site-vpn, kerio

I'm setting up a Site-to-Site VPN between my on-premises network and AWS VPC, and encountering an `INVALID_ID_INFORMATION` error during the phase 2 (Quick Mode) negotiation. The setup involves IPsec with the following parameters: `ikelifetime=1h` and `lifetime=8h`. My AWS Site-to-Site VPN tunnel options include configuring both phase 1 and phase 2 lifetimes. Additionally, we're using DH group 2 for the key exchange.

The logs from my on-premises VPN device (using StrongSwan) show the following sequence:

- Generating a Quick Mode request to AWS's IP address.
- Receiving an `INVALID_ID_INFORMATION` error in response.

The configurations for local and remote networks seem to match on both ends, with AWS VPC's CIDR being `10.0.0.0/16` and the on-premises network configured accordingly.

Despite these settings, the error persists, hindering the VPN tunnel's establishment. Furthermore, the AWS logs and metrics provide limited insight into this issue.

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing the `INVALID_ID_INFORMATION` error during the Quick Mode negotiation between my on-premises network and AWS VPC?
2. How can I access more detailed logs or metrics within AWS to diagnose this issue further?
3. Are there any recommended steps or configurations I might be overlooking that could resolve this error?

Any advice on troubleshooting this VPN setup or insights into obtaining more detailed diagnostic information from AWS would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should closely review the downloaded configuration file from AWS VPN gateway. You need to make sure the inside IP addresses are used and accurate. They are talked about here, albeit not the same type of scenario as yours. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/simulating-site-to-site-vpn-customer-gateways-strongswan/
I believe you’re dealing with a mismatch on those inside IP addresses. You’re probably trying to use your outside IP addresses as the ID.